# MySQL - How to organize databases into folders

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to organize these so they don't all show up in one list like this?

Thanks

```
mysql> show databases;
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| All databases list  |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all MySQL databases created will show up, as long as you have access to view (read) them.

Your best bet to filter out a sub-set of databases is to use a `like` statement such as:

`show databases like 'projectA%'`

(Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to have "catalogs" in MySQL. SQL Server and Sybase implement those, but not MySQL.

Having said that, you still can run multiple instances of MySQL on the same box.

Each one will:

- Save the data into a different [internal] directory.
- Will listen on a different network port.
- Will have a separate security (users, permissions).
- Could be the same or different version of MySQL.